# Web API - Deserializing body based on URL segment - Model Binder or Media Formatter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

So I've been reading up on Web API content negotiating and I'm a little confused trying to tie it together to find the solution to the problem I'm facing.

I'm using attribute binding so my Controller method looks like this:

```
    [Route("{user}/{platform}/profile")]
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task UpdateProfile([ModelBinder]AppUser user, Platform platform, [FromBody] IProfile profile)
```

Platform is an enum listing our various product platforms (not related to a software/OS platform) e.g. Alpha, Beta, Charlie. We have corresponding IProfile implementations AlphaProfile, BetaProfile, CharlieProfile.

The user and platform parameters deserialize just find and dandy. However I can't figure out the proper way to get my application to deserialize to the right object. Currently I have a IModelBinder implementation like this:

```
    public class ProfileModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {            
        object platformParameterFromQueryString;

        if (actionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("platform", out platformParameterFromQueryString))
        {
            Platform platformParameter;

            if (platformParameterFromQueryString == null || !Enum.TryParse<Platform>(platformParameterFromQueryString.ToString(), out platformParameter))
                throw new ArgumentException("platform parameter not found");

            if (platformParameter== Platform.Alpha)
            {
                var jsonContent = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                bindingContext.Model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlphaProfile>(jsonContent);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }



        return (bindingContext.Model != null);
    }
}
```

But I understand this isn't the intention of the modelbinder. What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution above worked but I wouldn't advise it.

The behaviour I'm looking for (conditional parameter binding based on other parameters) isn't native to the framework and while you could hack it into the model binder there's a number of reasons it's a bad idea.

Your best option is to just have separate endpoints or logic inside the controller